# How to sort two fields with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mean, database

I'm trying to allow users to see trending posts. The general idea is to sort by the most recent posts (_id: -1) and then sort those by most upvotes (upvotes_count: -1) and then limiting the results (.limit(3)). This is a bit simplified, so please ignore this implementation of "trending posts".

Unfortunately, I'm not able to return two sorts in the way that I want. So with a collection of six posts, it returns the most recent three, but it doesn't then sort them by most upvotes. For instance:

Post 6 (upvotes: 1)
Post 5 (upvotes: 2)
Post 4 (upvotes: 1)

I want them to be sorted like so:

Post 5 (upvotes: 2)
Post 6 (upvotes: 1)
Post 4 (upvotes: 1)

I'm not so interested in what happens with ties, but at a minimum, I want the posts that have more upvotes to be listed higher than those with less upvotes.

Of course, I could write a method to sort these, but surely there is a way to do this with MongoDB.

Below are some of the ways I've tried to implement this sort.

```
// Use sort for date and then use it again for upvotes_count
Post.find()
    .sort({_id: -1})
    .sort({upvotes_count: -1})
    .limit(3)
    .exec( function(err, posts) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        console.log(posts);
        res.json(posts);
     });

// Use sort for date, limit the results to three, and then
// use it again for upvotes_count
Post.find()
    .sort({_id: -1})
    .limit(3)
    .sort({upvotes_count: -1})
    .exec( function(err, posts) {
        if (err) res.send(err)
        console.log(posts);
        res.json(posts);
    });

// Use sort for date and upvotes_count in one step.
Post.find()
    .sort({_id: -1, upvotes_count: -1})
    .limit(3)
    .exec( function(err, posts) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        console.log(posts);
        res.json(posts);
     });
```

None have worked.

Answer (score 15):

Refer to [`sort()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) definition.

`sort({_id: -1, upvotes_count: -1})`

means sort the `_id` firstly, then sort `upvotes_count` by desc order only for those **same** `_id` posts. Unfortunately, the `_id` is [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/), which is 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:

- a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
- a 3-byte machine identifier,
- a 2-byte process id, and
- a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

It is hard to get the same `ObjectId`. Namely, the `_id` of every record should be unique in this document. As a result, the result of your test codes are just ordered by `_id` desc.

Here is one example,

```
+---------+---------------+
| _id     |  upvote_count |
+---------+---------------+
|  1      |      5        |
|  4      |      7        |
|  3      |      9        |
|  4      |      8        |
```

The result of `sort({_id: -1, upvotes_count: -1})` should be

```
+---------+---------------+
| _id     |  upvote_count |
+---------+---------------+
|  4      |      8        |
|  4      |      7        |
|  3      |      9        |
|  1      |      5        |
```

The `upvote_count` would be sorted for same `_id`.

However, in this case. There is on same `_id` in this case.

```
+---------+---------------+
| _id     |  upvote_count |
+---------+---------------+
|  1      |      5        |
|  4      |      7        |
|  3      |      9        |
|  2      |      8        |
```

The result of `sort({_id: -1, upvotes_count: -1})` should be

```
+---------+---------------+
| _id     |  upvote_count |
+---------+---------------+
|  1      |      5        |
|  2      |      8        |
|  3      |      9        |
|  4      |      7        |
```

Comment: sort({_id: -1}) orders the items by most recent first. So once it has that list, I don't understand why it can't then sort them by upvotes_count.

Comment: @JonRoby,  `upvote_count` could be sorted only for same `_id`, however, there is no same `_id` in all document, so `upvote_count` cannot be sorted...

Comment: Refer to `sort` by multiple fields https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort

Answer (score 3):

You can find most up voted documents for certain times

### Most up voted in last 24 hours

```
var yesterday = Date.now()- 1000*60*60*24;

// assuming created_at contains time-stamp
find({created_at:{$gt:yesterday}}).sort({upvotes_count: -1}).limit(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.getPosts = function(number, callback) { 
  Post.find().sort({ upvotes_count: -1 }).select({ _id: 1 })
    .limit(number)
    .exec(
      function(err, projects) {
        callback(null, projects);
      }
    );
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.