# MongoDB, Mongoose default sorting order value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How can I sort the results of a query as the default order?

I have a select option which has sorts in ascending, descending and don't sort options.

I know there's `.sort({price: 1})` `.sort({price: -1})`. 
but how can I sort by the original order? and I don't want to use `.sort({$natural: 1})` because i sort the results based on multiple fields.

Comment: What do you mean by "original order"?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Where you able to sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by original order. If you want to sort multiple fields, you can check at this link [How to sort two fields with mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027471/how-to-sort-two-fields-with-mongoose?rq=1)

Hope it helps